# Change CSS style depending on textbox value onload in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to make some buttons CSS change onload depending on the textbox value using jQuery 1.9.1 but I'm unable to do that. Suppose, after the page loads, if the value of a textbox is `YES` then button color should be green and if the value of another textbox is `NO` then the button color should be blue. In HTML, only "blue" class is assigned as default but jQuery has to change that onload. Here's my code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.btn').load(function () {
        var isYes = $(this).next('.assignCheck').val('Y');
        if (isYes) {
            $(this).toggleClass('color-blue color-green');
        }
    });
});
```

[**JSFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cygud48a/1/)

How can I change the CSS style depending on a value given after the page loads?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE**

Working Solution,

```
$('.btn').each(function () {
    if ($(this).next('.assignCheck').val() == 'y') {
        $(this).toggleClass('color-blue color-green');
    }
});
```

[**JSFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cygud48a/3/)

Your first problem is this line:

```
var isYes = $(this).next('.assignCheck').val('Y');
```

What that is doing isn't testing it, it's assigning 'y' to the value of `.assignCheck`. What you need is something like:

```
var isYes = ($(this).next('.assignCheck').val() == 'y');
```

or just

```
if ($(this).next('.assignCheck').val() == 'y') {
    $(this).toggleClass('color-blue color-green');
}
```

More info @ http://api.jquery.com/val/.

Secondly, `.load()` has been deprecated, use `each()` instead since the code will run on document load anyway.

```
$('.btn').each(function() { ...
```

Comment: that was my first guess but it didn't work. Tried again after your post. Still not working.

Comment: Reworked it to use each(). Working now in fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cygud48a/4/